# How can I upload a 'file' to S3 by creating a temp file, using AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, lambda, boto3

I am writing a lambda function, whose goal is to download a .json file from s3, modify its contents, then reupload to the same bucket under a different key.

So in my s3, I have a 'cloud' bucket cloud/folder/foo.json

```
>>> foo.json
{
   "value1": "abc",
   "value2": "123"
}
```

I want to download it, change a couple of things accordingly and re-upload it to the same place as bar.json

I have the first part sort of working, in that it downloads the contents of the file and modifies the contents, but everything is now a python dictionary object.

```
import boto3
import json


def get_json():
    client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = client.get_object(Bucket='cloud', Key='folder/foo.json')
    data = response['Body'].read()
    bar = json.loads(data)
    bar["value-1"] = "do-re-mi"

    #TODO: implement uploading here   

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    get_json()
    return 'Hello from Lambda'
```

So now...

```
>>> bar
{
   "value1": "do-re-mi",
   "value2": "123"
}
```

The bar variable is correct, but is a dictionary object. How can I go about directly uploading to that bucket as bar.json?
I saw other examples here but I am not keen on putting in my AWS secret or access keys anywhere. I assume because I am using lambda I cannot create a file on the machine, when I try to do something like below:

```
g = open('myfile.json', 'w')
g.write(json.dumps(bar, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
g.close()

with open('myfile.json', 'rb') as f:
    client.upload_fileobj(f, 'cloud', 'bar.json')
```

I get a "errorType": "IOError",
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'myfile.json'"

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `StringIO` or `tempfile`? How much memory does your instance have? Lambda will let you write to `/tmp` add that to your path if you want to write it down to a FS: [thread in reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/5mlgp4/aws_lambda_s3_and_temporary_files/)

Comment: @monchitos82 Thank you very much! Didn't realize lambda supported a filesystem. This is super helpful to know

Comment: glad to help @user5494969 your question title is misleading, you might want to fix that one for this to help others in the same situation.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to monchitos82 I have learned that you can write to /tmp in lambda. So all I had to do was add that to the beginning of my files and it worked.

```
g = open('/tmp/myfile.json', 'w')
g.write(json.dumps(bar, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
g.close()

with open('/tmp/myfile.json', 'rb') as f:
    client.upload_fileobj(f, 'cloud', 'bar.json')
```

Comment: There is [500MB of space in `/tmp`](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/#functions).  It's good practice to clean up your temp files, because sometimes you'll find that your function is running in a container where the same function has already recently run within the past few minutes ("container reuse") and with enough of that, you could unexpectedly run out of space.  Concurrent invocations don't share containers but consecutive ones can.  It's not a security issue, though -- nobody else will stumble on your files, because it's wiped when the container is finally destroyed due to inactivity.

Comment: @user5494969 can you please post the final code which includes the temp file creation....

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you don't even need to write a temporary file; [`Key.open_write`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.open_write) seems to give you a writable file to which you can `.dump` your JSON. I'm still not sure if it's implemented in AWS currently.

There's [`key.set_contents_from_string`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_string) which should work provided that you have enough spare RAM for `.dumps()`.